# shell script to open many terminals from a parent terminal and execute different cmds

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

I want to open 5 terminals from a parent terminal and place these terminals on the screen properly so that each terminal can be viewed properly at the same time.
Also, i want to execute differnet commands in each terminal.

Can you help me please?

Thanks,
pawan

Comment: Try `tmux`.  For example https://github.com/chicks-net/chicks-home/blob/master/bin/start_tmux opens up half a dozen tabs and runs commands in a few of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gnome-terminal` command to open a new terminal. 
Also if you want to execute a command in new terminal you can use following command :-

`gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cat > /tmp/sample'"`

This will open a new terminal which will open sample file for writing. You can place your commands or scripts. Also if you want 5 terminals, procedure is same.

Comment: Gnome wouldn't normally be found on a server.

Comment: @lain I know most of servers don't have Gnome installed. Since the question didn't specify any linux distro or method through which he wants to access terminals so I gave a generic answer. If you know some other method than we will appreciate and will learn something new.

Comment: This isn't a generic answer it's actually quite specific to gnome.

Comment: There's no indication the OP has Gnome and I don't see any question about it in the comments.  Plus `gnome-terminal` is a pain to automate.

Answer (score 1):

[Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) would be one way to solve your problem. It can open several terminals by splitting the screen & more. [This answer at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/200382/how-do-i-get-tmux-to-open-up-a-set-of-panes-without-manually-entering-them) will be helpful.